# Check if multiple files with specific names arrive in a directory. Only when they arrive continue or else keeping looking for those files

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code needs to look for 3 files with specific names in a directory.For example: `123_xy_report.xlsm`, `789_ab_file.xlsm`, `222_ftp_review.xlsm`.
Only when all these files arrive, continue or else keep looking for the files until they arrive.

I have tried glob and fnmatch, but unable to get it right to look for these specific files.

```
while True:
    os.chdir(dir)
    filelist=['08282019_xy_report.xlsm','08282019_ab_file.xlsm','08282019_ftp_review.xlsm']
    if all([os.path.isfile(f)for f in filelist]):
        print('All files exists')
        break
    else:
        print('waiting for files to arrive')
        time.sleep(60)
```

The files will have the datetime as prefix,so the files comes with new date every day.

Comment: What *specifically* did you try, and which part weren't you able to get right?

Comment: Hi jon, I have posted the code I tried, it worked fine for today but the file comes with different datetime tommorrow.

Comment: Then don't you want to start by building the correct filenames *given the current day*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the files changes names after the date but however arrive at random times. Then you need to make a list with names formatted to your files with the current days date. This works. I am sure it can be made shorter but because of the filename requirements this is the best I came up with. Hope it helps!

```
import os
from datetime import date
import time

dir = ""
names = ["_xy_report.xlsm", "_ab_file.xlsm", "_ftp_review.xlsm"]
formatted_list = []

while True:
# Change to needed directory
    os.chdir(dir)
# To days date formatted to list
    days_date = str(date.today()).replace('-', '')
    for n in names:
        formatted_list.append(f"{days_date + n}")
# check if all files has arrived yet
    if all([os.path.isfile(f)for f in formatted_list]):
        print("All files exist")
        break
    else:
        print(f"Waiting for {formatted_list} to arrive")
        time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Thank you Stian .This solution worked. Appreicate your help.

Comment: Happy to help @user11996418 :)

Answer (score -1):

Almost there...

If you are looking for all of those files and then, and only then, start doing work, then it doesn't matter in which order you wait for them.

I suggest this simple solution:

```
import os.path
import time

filelist = ['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt']

for f in filelist:
    print('waiting for ' + f)
    while not os.path.isfile(f):
        time.sleep(2)
    print(f + ' found')

print('all files found')
```

This script need to be in the same folder you search OR you can append the absolute path to the file names OR `chdir` to that directory